# Is there a content type "root" default template in Drupal?

Tags: drupal-7, content-type

I've created a new content type, say "Products".  Is there some kind of default routing and templating based on the content type ?

For example, can I access my "root" content type by going to www.example.com/products/ ?

And would I also simply need to edit a certain tpl for that content type "root" page (for example the /products/ page that lists all products ?

For now, the solution I've got is to create a node of type "Page" called "Products", create a view and assign this view to the Products page.  Then, create a TPL for this node (wich would list the products).

I find this solution a bit long .. is there another way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I've created a new content type, say "Products". Is there some kind of
>   default routing and templating based on the content type ?

- No, you can only edit (by core) the content type fields etc through the admin inderface.

> For now, the solution I've got is to create a node of type "Page"
>   called "Products", create a view and assign this view to the Products
>   page. Then, create a TPL for this node (wich would list the products).

- You can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module to create lists of data. Use tpl.php files (see the [template suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656)) for the display of each page, node, block etc. I would suggest to not add a views inside a node tpl through code but as a block.

Did I understand well?